# Weird scrolling issue in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have a very complex issue, which although i doubt anyone will know the answer to, i thought i'd give it a shot as you're a clever bunch of people.

Over on my website (link below) i have a problem where, when viewed in a mobile browser or when a normal web-browser is made smaller, for example on an iPhone, the pages have to be scrolled to be fully viewed. However, when the "Tour" page is viewed in a mobile browser, it displays without a scroll.

When the #tabs div is removed from the Tour page, the display has a scroll on iDevices - which is very weird - when the #tabs div is there, no scrolling. ALL pages on the site, excluding the "Tour" page have this scrolling issue on iDevices and on Firefox when the browser is made smaller.

I basically don't want users to have to scroll at all when they're viewing on smaller resolution screens.

The theme i've created is a child theme of twentyeleven on Wordpress.

[Homepage](http://odesk.n8geeks.com)
[Tour page](http://odesk.n8geeks.com/tour)

Thanks in advance,
Nick.

Comment: Let me get this correct, you don't want scrolling on the homepage or the tour page...

Comment: In what case did you say your website had no scrollbar? If you don't want the scrollbar, just put overflow:hidden in the body tag. You still will need to use the arrows to scroll down. There is just too much contents in both of your pages. In your homepage, you have 1263 by 845. And in your tour page, 1263 by 1162. As you can see, both of those heights are above 600 which will create scrollbars in smaller resolution.

Comment: I obviously don't mind the vertical scrolling, it's the horizontal scrolling that is the issue, which I cannot figure out for the life of me as to why it's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a fundamental problem with the site's design scheme right now. Next time you should really keep this in mind as you are creating/editing the template you downloaded.

For mobile and tablet users you need to pick 1 of 3 options:

1. Create an alternative mobile version of your website, *or*
2. Design the page how it should actually be done: using % or EM for a 'liquid design' (meaning the site and content appropriately adjusts according to content)
3. Use a CSS hack such as "display" or "overflow" none

Number 2 is definitely your best option here. If you're getting horizontal scroll bars you need to check your widths, paddings, margins, etc and make sure nothing equals < 100%. Also consider what content is being added and modified as the page naturally progresses, that is probably your issue. (as you mentioned above, the "tour page" varies dependent upon #tabs

Liquid Layouts:
http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/liquid/

Jquery Mobile:
http://jquerymobile.com/

Answer (score 0):

Like TheChristopher answered above, you should define the page and everything in it by %, px, or em. I suggest that you use a firebug add-on to figure out how all the contents fits in and work. Take div or sections out from your page and see if you can get it to work, before adding those sections back in. Don't forget to save back-up files before you try this approach. :)